# Is the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane enough for CJK speakers?

Tags: unicode, cjk

The Question: "Is supporting only the Unicode BMP sufficient to enable native Chinese / Japanese / Korean speakers to use an application in their native language?"

I'm most concerned with Japanese speakers right now, but I'm also interested in the answer for Chinese people as well.  If an application only supported characters on the BMP - would it make the application unusable for Chinese/Japanese speakers (i.e. app did not allow data entry / display of supplemental characters)?

I'm not asking if the BMP is the only thing you would ever need for any kind of application (clearly not - especially for all language in the entire world).  I'm asking for CJK speakers, in a professional context, for a modern kind of ordinary app that deals with general free text entry (including, names, places, etc.) - is the BMP generally enough?

Even if only supporting the BMP is not correct - would it be pretty close / "good enough"? Would the lack of supplemental characters in an application only be an occasional minor inconvenience; or would a Japanese speaker, for example, consider the application completely broken?  Especially considering that they would always be able to work around the problem by spelling out problematic words with Hiragana/Katakana?

What about Chinese speakers who don't have a fallback option, would the lack of supplemental characters be considered a show-stopping problem?

I'm considering general professional context here - not social or gaming stuff.  As an example, there's a lot of the emoticons on the supplemental planes - but I personally would not consider an English app that did not support Unicode emoticon characters to be "broken", at least for most professional use.

The application I'm dealing with right now is written in Java, but I think this question applies more generally.  Knowing the answer will also help me (regardless of language) get a better handle on how much effort I'd have to go through with regard to font support.

---

EDIT

Clarification: by "supports only the BMP" - I intend that the application would handle supplemental characters gracefully.
Unsupported characters (including the BMP surrogate code blocks) would be dealt with similarly to how most applications deal with ASCII control codes and other undesirable characters - filtered/disallowed for  data entry and "dealt with" for display if that were necessary (filtered out or replaced with the unicode replacement character).

Comment: I don't think restricting input like this but still supporting them elsewhere is nice. If you want to restrict input do it with more useful criteria than "it's in the BMP". Sticking to the BMP is useful if you want to assume UCS-2 everywhere (which may potentially make code simpler), but if you're going to support UTF-16 anyway, the code will not be any simpler. Think about what exactly you want to restrict on input. Maybe you want to forbid confusables or have some other security concerns (relevant http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/)? As a user I find arbitrary input filters quite annoying.

Comment: @ebyrob no, I mean that "supporting UTF-16 *but limiting to the BMP*" hardly results in simpler code than just "supporting UTF-16, period". None of this predates UTF-8, but UTF-16 is alive and well, is actually ubiquitous, and is extremely relevant here: the application is written in Java. My assumption that UTF-16 support is still required comes from "(including the BMP surrogate code blocks)", which only makes sense in the context of UTF-16 (well, and pedantically if you remove the "BMP" part; technically the surrogate scalar values are not part of any Unicode plane, not even the BMP).

Comment: @ebyrob the OP states that they want to "handle supplemental characters gracefully", which means you need to filter out or replace the 4-byte characters. You can't do that without code that detects them (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt-int-). (That code is not particularly complex, but it's definitely not as simple as simply pretending all characters use 2-bytes, i.e. UCS-2)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Right, so this is just a variation of "Here's why your question is useless."  clearly true since 2 = 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people who might be looking for an actual answer to the actual question: the application that prompted this question is now in production allowing only characters from the BMP (actually a limited subset).

Multiple international customers using Korean language in production - Japanese going live soon.  Chinese is in planning (I have my doubts that the BMP will be sufficient for that, but we'll see I guess).

It's fine - no reported issues related to unsupported characters.

But that's just anecdotal evidence, really.  Just because my customers were fine with it - that doesn't mean yours will be.  For context, customers of the app are international companies, hundreds of employees using the application to process hundreds of thousands of their customers.

Comment: Can you comment on how you overcame the issues in my answer. For example, do you use the default fonts so that the system selects based on the OS language? Do your customers ever use two or three CJK languages at once?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately CJK support in Unicode is broken. The BMP is not enough to properly support CJK, but worse than that even if you do implement full support for all Unicode pages it is still broken.

The basic problem is that they tried to merge characters from all three languages that look kinda similar but are not really the same. The result is that they only look right if you select the correct font to display them. For example, a particular character will only look right to a Chinese person if you render it with a Chinese font, and only look right to a Japanese person if you render it with a Japanese font.

There is no universal font. There is no way to determine which language a character is supposed to be from, so you have to somehow guess which font to use. You can try to examine the system language or some other hack like that. You can't support two languages in the same document unless you have additional metadata. If you get raw Unicode strings without any indication of what language they are in, you are screwed.

It's a total disaster. You need to talk to your clients to figure out their needs and how they indicate to their systems what font to use for broken Unicode characters.

Edit: Also need to mention, some characters required for people's names are missing from Unicode. Later revisions are better, but of course you also need updated fonts to take advantage of them.

Comment: Wow.  Just wow.  Is this true?!!  How come we never hear about this?  Are there yet new Unicode planes to address this problem?  Is it some other way surmountable?

Comment: You probably don't hear about it because you aren't a developer in one of the affected languages. Most Japanese and Chinese developers still use their own local encoding schemes like Shift-JIS.

Comment: I don't understand how using Shift-JIS (or Big5 or GB18030 or...) solves any of these problems. It seems to me that it just does not.

Comment: Shift-JIS supports the characters that are missing from Unicode and necessary for people's names. By specifying that encoding (with metadata) it also helps select a suitable font.

Comment: @ゼーロ Fair enough, but you actually didn't mention missing characters in this answer. However, I can't tell the difference between "(with metadata)" in this comment and "unless you have additional metadata" like you said in the post. It seems to me like the same solution to the same problem, and not specific to the encoding used.

Comment: Well, the point of unicode is that you don't need metadata, you can just encode everything. Except you can't, for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of CJK codepoints are defined in the BMP, however CJK Ideographs are not.  So if you do not need to support Ideographs, then the BMP is fine, otherwise it is not.

However, I would consider any implementation that does not recognize and process UTF-16 surrogates, even if it does not handle the Unicode codepoints they represent, to be broken.

Comment: Serious question (not intended to be snarky) - do you speak any of the CJK languages?

Comment: No, I do not.  I am merely stating what is documented in the Unicode standard.

Comment: Yep - understood.  Perhaps I'd be better off deleting and re-framing the question to be about Unicode 2.0 instead of the BMP.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to Unicode 2.0? The current standard is 6.3.0.

Comment: Nice point Remy! I think that the common sense approach is to add a minimal support for Unicode, always to use well known libraries when processing text (don't try to reinvent the wheel, especially here!). Once released, let the users report bugs and fix them, nobody can afford to fully test Unicode support. It may be helpful to pay someone with i18n experience on making an audit and to create a minimal checklist for you.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are a fond developer or developing an operating systems you should not care about that, let the OS layer deal with it.

Just implement proper Unicode support in your application and allow the operating system to deal with how the characters are types and displayed.

If you are using custom fonts in your application you may be in trouble

In the end to answer your question: **NO**, Unicode support is not only BMP and you need to support Unicode.

Comment: That was not the question.

Comment: @Shorn : I know very well what was your question and the short answer is bolded in my answer, even you may not like it. I worked for many years in software internationalization and I know how complex it would be. You have to provide limited support for outside BMP in your app, meaning that you will have to address all bugs caused by your code and let users know that the Unicode support is limited to what the operating system and used libraries provides. Obviously, you will have to update your app if the used libraries are updated. And BTW, never prevent user from entering outside BMP text!

Comment: You're being ridiculous.  Any halfway decent application should be fully responsible for the peculiarities of any operating system it will expect to be run on.  Separation of concerns should not mean ignorance of knowledge.